# AJAX http GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm currently teaching myself some AJAX through jQuery.

I've written a straight forward get request to load in data from an xml file into a section with a class of container.

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<section class="container">

</section>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
<script src="xmlFeed.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using a local xml file after i created to dummy post on a WordPress site and got the feed.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >

<channel>
    <title>Biz-Tech.ie &#187; Biz-Tech News</title>
    <atom:link href="http://www.biz-tech.ie/category/biz-tech-news/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>http://www.biz-tech.ie</link>
    <description></description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sat, 11 Oct 2014 17:39:16 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-US</language>
        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <generator>http://wordpress.org/?v=4.0</generator>
    <item>
        <title>News</title>
        <link>http://www.biz-tech.ie/news/</link>
        <comments>http://www.biz-tech.ie/news/#comments</comments>
        <pubDate>Sat, 11 Oct 2014 17:39:16 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[Michael]]></dc:creator>
                <category><![CDATA[Biz-Tech News]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.biz-tech.ie/?p=170</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[Output Box &#8211; Random strings/passwords will display here. Load objects used for random string generation into the &#8220;Object Input Box&#8221; above. Objects above can be characters, words, sentences, etc. Test by clicking the &#8220;Generate random strings&#8221; button above to generate 10, 14 character, random strings from the default input objects. NOTICE: Tool uses Javascript method Math.random() pseudorandom generator to obtain [&#8230;]]]></description>
                <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>Output Box &#8211; Random strings/passwords will display here.<br />
Load objects used for random string generation into the &#8220;Object Input Box&#8221; above. Objects above can be characters, words, sentences, etc.<br />
Test by clicking the &#8220;Generate random strings&#8221; button above to generate 10, 14 character, random strings from the default input objects.<br />
NOTICE: Tool uses Javascript method Math.random() pseudorandom generator to obtain random string. Do not use for critical random results.<br />
Privacy of Data: This tool is built-with and functions-in Client Side JavaScripting, so only your computer will see or process your data input/output.</p>
]]></content:encoded>
            <wfw:commentRss>http://www.biz-tech.ie/news/feed/</wfw:commentRss>
        <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

And finally here is the ajax GET request along with a function to parse the xml into the container section in my html:

```
 $(doccument).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"feed.xml",
      dataType:"xml",
      success:xmlParser
   });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
   $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
      $("#container").append('<h3>'+ $(this).find("title").text()+'</h3><br />'
         '<a href="'+ $(this).find("link").text()+'></a>'
         '<p>'+ $(this).find("description").text()+'</p>'
         '<p><h5>Author: '+ $(this).find("dc:creator").text()+'</h5></p>'
         );
   });
}
```

The function isn't working and for the life of me I have no idea why as I can see an syntax errors.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' 
xmlFeed.js, line 13 character 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few problems with your code.

**1).** The way you are concatenate strings in javascript is not correct. Use this syntax:

```
   $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
      $(".container").append('<h3>'+ $(this).find("title").text()+'</h3><br />' +
         '<a href="'+ $(this).find("link").text()+'"></a>' +
         '<p>'+ $(this).find("description").text()+'</p>' +
         '<p><h5>Author: '+ $(this).find('dc\\:creator, creator').eq(0).text()+'</h5></p>'
         );
   });
```

Note `+` operator, it is used for string concatenation.

**2).** One more problem. You missed a closing quote in link construction string, which breaks HTML and hides all subsequent content:

```
'<a href="' + $(this).find("link").text() + '"></a>'
                                             ^-- add this guy here
```

**3).** One more thing: your selector must be `$(".container")` since `container` is a class, not id.

**4).** And finally there is one more little detail about how you should retrieve `dc:creator` node. Since this node is namespaced you need to escape it like this:

```
.find("dc\\:creator")
```

However it still doesn't guarantee that it will work in all browsers. You probably should do something like this:

```
$(this).find('dc\\:creator, creator').eq(0)
```

You provide two selectors here. The second selector `creator` will work in Chrome, and the first (escaped) in Firefox.

5). Also just in case, `doccument` is a probably a typo, but anyway it should be `document`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/0Z2tJJ3JANtJq30CNUDD?p=preview

Comment: I'm now getting a console error at the beginning of my xmlFeed.js  .xmlFeed.js, line 1 character 1. SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

Comment: It means that jQuery is not loaded. Make sure it's goes before `xmlFeed.js`.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to build the plunker demo. I copied pasted and renamed my files to match yours. I am still getting a console error. SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
script.js, line 1 character 1

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `doccument` instead of `document` in your `$(doccument).ready`.

Comment: I've updated the syntax to correct both your points to this:           $(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"feed.xml",
      dataType:"xml",
      success:xmlParser
   });
});

function xmlParser(xml) {
   $(xml).find("item").each(function(){
      $("#container").append('<h3>'+ $(this).find("title").text()+'</h3><br />' +
         '<a href="'+ $(this).find("link").text()+'></a>' +
         '<p>'+ $(this).find("description").text()+'</p>' +
         '<p><h5>Author: '+ $(this).find("dc:creator").text()+'</h5></p>'
         );
   });
}

Comment: I am still getting this console error:'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string '

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem is *"**I am using a local xml file** ..."*. If you look at your console I am pretty sure that you are getting an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin error". This is a browser model security problem. Have a read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) if you need more info.

In short though Access-Control-Allow-Origin errors occurs when you call a Web Service such as do a GET request for an XML file, from a domain that is different from the one hosting your HTML page. In you case I believe that you are your HTML file is on your hard drive while the Web Service is called on the localhost.

For development purposes you can use [this chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi). That will work for now.

Comment: I apologies. I shouldn't have used the word local. I have all the file in the same folder on my desktop called New folder. the folder structure is: index.html, xmlFeed.js and feed.xml